# How do I get rid of white lines in wall corners showing up after painting?

Tags: painting, primer

I'm painting the interior of our house. One room I started with the previous owner had painted it a light mushroom color. I'm painting it with a color that's a little lighter. I'm using Behr paint. I was told at Home Depot's paint department since it was already painted and similar color I don't need primer. So I painted the room two top coats. But I noticed I'm seeing (I think it was there before I painted too) a thin white line in the corners. I took several photos of the corner. Here is a link to them:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
<sup>*Click for larger view*</sup>

I don't know the cause of this, but I would like to cover it up with the new color. Would a Latex primer and then two top coats take care of this? Or should I go directly with an Oil primer? Or get a quarter of each and try one in each corner to see what happens? Or is there something else that should be done? Or is this an optical illusion and I'm chasing a ghost here? :-) Thanks!

Comment: Your drop box link doesn't work for me.  Use the editing tools to embed your images directly into your question please.

Comment: This may be an optical illusion.  Hit it with direct, bright light and see if you still see the variation.

Comment: It's hard to tell but it kinda looks like you used a roller only, and didn't use a brush to do the corner first?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo I'm using a Husky LED stand light. But I have used no lights during the day and a desk lamp alone and I see the same thing.

Comment: @gregmac I used a roller at first and then went back to did the corners with a brush. Could the previous owner have used caulk in the corners and that's what is being seen?

Answer (score 2):

If the prior owner used caulk, and they were really dumb and didn't use paintable latex caulk, then its possible that this would be the result.

Regardless, obviously the paint isn't taking properly here - so yes, the answer here is get a quart of primer go over the edges with a brush, let it dry, and redo the corners.